# Swift: Is it possible to save last recipient after sending e-mail?

Tags: swift, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

In my application i use `MFMailComposeViewController` to send e-mail. I set subject and message body in my code, but let user choose the recipient.
I want to save last recipient e-mail that user entered, so that next time when user tries to send e-mail, it would automatically fill in the 'to' field.
I know how to make it fill in in code, but is it even possible to get that e-mail address in the first place?

Comment: Sounds creepy to me. I mean that in a constructive way.

Comment: no no no, nothing creepy. it's just the thing about application, that user's (almost) always sending e-mail to same address. for example, i can hardcode my own e-mail with `mailComposer.setToRecipients()` in advance, but if i install it for my colleague, he will also be spamming my e-mail. ofc, he can enter it each time manually, but i'd like to simplify it for him

Comment: It's not possible, there is no way to get the recipients when composer is done as even having reference to MFMailComposeViewController you don't have property or anything to read the recipients.

Comment: that's what i wanted to know. thank you

Comment: You could also ask for favorite/most used email addresses and then add them as you previously said, using `setToRecipients`. Maybe AB test it and check whether users are willing to save them or not